# communication between android app (java) with windows app (vb.net) by web service

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, remote-access

I have  application Android  to control computer (restart,shutdown,...) by connecting Android application  with a Windows application (vb.net) through the Web Service 
I do not know where to start and how to contact Anyone who has any idea on the subject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a broad question and you asked for ideas let me pour some thoughts.

Where to start? Define a protocol for the web service that both parties understand. For example define an URI that the android client can push messages to (with PUT or POST) and the vb.net client can poll for updates (with GET). Since we use one URI here the payload sent to the URI must define what to do. The android client could for example post the message '{command:restart}" then the vb.net client should know that he has to restart the machine if the message is received.

There are a few caveats here though. First the vb.net client needs to poll the URI to get the command. So between sending the command and executing it there is some delay. Even better, right now you don't even know if the command was executed or not. Also since there is no authentication everybody can issue commands to the web service. Sounds like tons of fun. For other parties at least. Lastly you need to clear the command from the URI if it was executed or updated. Else the machine would, in this example, go into a restart loop.

So the first problem may be solved with and extra URI where the android client can poll for some king of system state that the vb.net client provides. For example the vb.net client may send the message '{state:restarting}' to the URI before restarting. Of course the vb.net client needs to update that URI every time some event happens. The security issue? Security is hard. You may want to create a certificate and sign the requests sent so the server with it. Then the server can check if it was really you who sent this request. Or somebody that has your cert, replayed the request or found some way of breaking the whole stuff. So you additionally might want to use [TLS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) with some king of [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). You might already know this but I'm going to repeat it anyway: do not send credentials over an insecure network. Also base64 (used in [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)) is not some kind of encryption. The last problem may be solved with a nonce that can be included in the command. Or the vb.net client clears the command from the URI (with DELETE) when it received the command. It should update the status URI though so that the android client does not send the request again.

Or you drop the whole web service stuff use technologies like [Web Sockets](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Then the android client can send a command to the socket. The server receives to command and sends it to the vb.net socket. When the command is received by the vb.net socket it sends out some kind of delivery receipt to the server and executes the command. The server receives the receipt and sends a confirmation the the android client so that it known that the command *is going to be* executed.

As you see there is a lot do do when implementing such a solution so let me summarize:

- define you use cases. What operations must the system support and how are the participating parties involved in any case.
- find corner cases for each use case. For example the authentication problem that needs to be solved.
- do some research on technologies that support your idea at the best possible way. Maybe a web service is not the best solution? What is a web service anyway? (Seems to be some king of buzzword anyone uses). Maybe [Web Sockets](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [XML RPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/) or even [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) are better candidates?
- define a protocol for the components
- implement it

One last note. I know this is a rather long answer? that might spawn a lot of questions in the readers head. But, do not get discouraged! You don't have to do anything that I wrote here. Well except the security thing maybe.

Comment: Thank u 
 will read about this topics i 'm still student and this is my  graduation project
I do not know a lot about these topics